# Resharper: Is there a hotkey to disable it when in editor?

Tags: resharper, resharper-5.0

I just love resharper 5... its great but sometimes i would like to use the hotkey to disable the lines underlines etc etc in the code editor as it interferes with some other plugins i have...

Is there a hotkey to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may help: [Resharper shortcuts](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/keyboard-shortcuts.html)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd> toggles most of the analysis in the editor.